# Style in Vuejs and responsive

Tags: css, vue.js, responsive

I'm trying to style my data in Vuejs, I want every property to be
vertical. every item in conversationHistory should be vertical not on
the same line. how can I do that in vuejs? anyone can help?

```
<template>

<h2 class="Email">Messages</h2>

<div v-if="messages?.conversationHistory" >

{{ messages.conversationHistory[0].action }}
{{ messages.conversationHistory[0].messageId }}
{{ messages.conversationHistory[0].attachments }}
{{ messages.conversationHistory[0].body }}
{{ messages.conversationHistory[0].from }}
{{ messages.conversationHistory[0].to }}
{{ messages.conversationHistory[0].cc }}
{{ messages.conversationHistory[0].subject }}
{{ messages.conversationHistory[0].sent }}

 </div>
</template>

<script>

import axios from 'axios';


export default {
    name: 'message-api',
    data(){
        return{
            messages: null,
            
        }
    },

    created() {
        axios.get(`http://sa-test-task-2022.s3-website.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/messages`)
            .then(response => {
                // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
                this.messages = response.data
            })
            .catch(e => {
                this.errors.push(e)
            });
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's preferable to generate a layout that is easy to style. In this case these lines could be wrapped with span

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `white-space` property which is used to handled white space inside an element. To achieve the line break you can use `pre-line` value which will collapse the sequence of whitespace into a single whitespace.

```
div {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Or else you can also directly wrap the content inside `<pre>` element in the HTML template itself.

```
<pre>
  {{ ... }}
  {{ ... }}
  {{ ... }}
  ...
</pre>
```

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    messages: {
        conversationHistory: [{
        action: 'Alpha',
        messageId: 123,
        body: 'hello'
      }]
    }
  }
})
```

```css
p {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(msg, index) in messages.conversationHistory" :key="index">
    <p>{{ msg.action }}
    {{ msg.messageId }}
    {{ msg.body }}</p>
    
<pre>
    {{ msg.action }}
    {{ msg.messageId }}
    {{ msg.body }}
</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have fetch the data but somehow I'm not able to display it properly , its an email thread.  can you see this and I hope  you understand this better.

Comment: Can you see my script thats the Api email thread that i'm trying to display . Can you help?

Comment: By adding this css `div { white-space: pre-line; }` will resolve your problem or you can add a class in the div element and then apply this style to that class.

Comment: .grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10%;
  width:367px;
  height: 46vh;
  margin: 15px 10px 10px 45px;
  white-space: pre-line;
}

Comment: this is my css for the div .

Comment: I did not see any grid in your code. Now it is going in some different direction. i added my answer as per your requirement and code you mentioned in post.

Comment: You want to show each expression in a new line and that's what I worked and it is showing like that.

Comment: yes Rohit bhai, its in different line how. I have to manage it . now I have to make a delete button to so i can delete all this and when refresh the whole email conversation comes back again. but thank you again Bhai.